# Strict variable declaration in Scheme

Tags: scheme, strict, variable-declaration

Does Scheme lisp provide any lib. similar to perl "strict" variable declaration?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to be more specific than "like some Perl feature"? Perhaps give an example of what you want to write and how you want the language to handle it.

Comment: If I forget to add any variable in "let", then scheme will not raise any error/warning, but it assumes it to be "nil". Same way, if I access my DPL (dynamic property list e.g., (list nil 'a 1 'b 2)) and if property doesn't exist (in this example 'c') then also it will return nil. This behavior hides bugs in my code and so I want to know that by somehow Scheme will generate warning/error message in these cases.

Comment: @Tanmay As far as I can tell, R5RS doesn't provide any functions for dealing with property lists.  Also, `(list nil 'a 1 'b 2)` doesn't look like an ordinary property list to me.  If you're using some kind of library for dealing with these data structures, error handling is that library's responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

Compared to Perl, Scheme is pretty strict and clean to begin with (for instance, referencing an undeclared variable will raise an exception in most implementations).  Compile-time warnings are an implementation quality issue.  Which Scheme implementation are you using?